# Why am I getting this Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement error using python?

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a mysql database with one table that I'm trying to import from CSV using python.

The error I'm getting is:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

But I have only 1 field in the table, so I am only using 1 parameter.

This is the table in MySQL:

```
desc billing_info;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| InvoiceId | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
import csv
source_dir = 'source_files/aws_bills/'
source_file = 'test_data.csv'
source = source_dir + source_file
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx',
                            host='xxxx',
                            database='aws_bill')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(source)
sql = "INSERT INTO billing_info (InvoiceId) VALUES (%i)"
for row in csv_data:  
    cursor.execute(sql, row)
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `row` variable has more than one value in it, maybe you meant:

```
for row in csv_data:  
    cursor.execute(sql, (row[0],))  # a one-tuple with the first element in the row..
```

also, the mysql connector usually wants you to use `%s` for any type of parameter, i.e.:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO billing_info (InvoiceId) VALUES (%s)"
```

**update:** your second issue is that you haven't opened the file, i.e.:

```
import os
import mysql.connector
import csv

# source_dir = 'source_files/aws_bills/'
# source_file = 'test_data.csv'
# source = source_dir + source_file
source = os.path.join('source_files', 'aws_bills', 'test_data.csv')
sql = "INSERT INTO billing_info (InvoiceId) VALUES (%s)"

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx', host='xxxx', database='aws_bill')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
try:
    with open(source, 'rb') as fp:
        for row in csv.reader(fp):
            cursor.execute(sql, (row[0],))

    cursor.close()
    mydb.commit()
except:
    mydb.rollback()
finally:
    mydb.close()
```

Comment: OK, thanks! When I try exactly that (copy/pasting from your answer) I now get this error: `mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 's' for column 'InvoiceId' at row 1` Which is the error I got before I substituted `VALUES (%s)` for `VALUES (%s)`. That's when I got the error I posted in the OP. Thanks for the answer, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: That error means that the data you're sending in is not an integer. Try printing out the `row` variable before you call `cursor.execute(...)`, maybe you're hitting the title row..?

Comment: I printed out the row variable and got a surprise. It's printing out the literal string that I used for the name of the CSV file! [row](https://pastebin.com/S1iKjs1a

These are the lines causing the problem: `source_dir = 'source_files/aws_bills/'
source_file = 'test_data.csv'
source = source_dir + source_file`  Not sure why that's happening. How can I declare the file correctly so that the program reads the file?

Comment: I realized the I forgot to open the file before reading it. So I did that with these lines:  `with open(source) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')` Now when I print row, this is what I see: https://pastebin.com/e3jSLYEp

But I am still unable to insert the rows into the database because they are surrounded by brackets and single quotes like this: `['201916750911995518611919164']`. This is how my code looks now: https://pastebin.com/p9ZLL00c  How can I strip the brackets and single quotes from the rows?

Comment: I've updated my answer. What you're receiving from the csv reader are rows, with one column each, i.e. a list with one element per row. The `(row[0],)` - note the trailing comma - extracts the data from the first/only column and passes it til the cursor.  MySQL probably doesn't care if you pass a string version of the numeric value in an insert, but if it did then the solution would be `(int(row[0]),)`.

Comment: OK thank you! I really like the tip to use os.path. I will start using that!

When I run the code exactly as presented (copied the whole thing into a separate file) nothing happens when I run the code. I tried printing out the 'row' value and still there's nothing. If I remove the reading options from the open statement like this: `with open(source) as fp:` I get ONE line printed out:`['200176595756546201775238333']`.

I've altered my own code (based on some of your recommendations) and got python to read all the lines of the column: https://pastebin.com/Ui3n9s5d

Comment: I also changed the column I am importing so that the values will be unique. I also deleted the header line so that the title of the column wouldn't appear. The original column I tried only have one value repeated. If I uncomment the sql write statement: `cursor.execute(sql, (row[0],))` only ONE line prints out, instead of printing all of them. And NOTHING gets written to the database: `cursor.execute(sql, (row[0],))`  :(

Comment: Also in my own code I get rid of the brackets and quotes in the list using the join command: `row = (', '.join(row))`